# laravel eloquent query first letter of field in collection

Tags: php, laravel

Does any one know how to query in a collection using eloquent using the where statement to see if the first letter in a field matches the queried letter. If someone know of another way to do this other than eloquent could you leave me an example thanks

what I have is just a simple query which just gets a collection but I want to query the first letter and select only those which matches in the query

```
$tags = Tag::orderBy('name', 'asc')->paginate(40);
```

Need to be like

```
$tags = Tag::orderBy('name', 'asc')->where(first letter', '=', 'L')->paginate(40);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the SQL `LIKE` condition.

`->where($field, 'LIKE', $letter.'%');`

`LIKE` compares strings to match the given string. The percent sign (%) is a wildcard.

Comment: Do you know how to append the query string to the links e.g $tags->links() need to append alpha Input

Comment: @KDM I am not sure what you are asking. If you're just appending a string to a link URLs end query strings like http:://somedomain.com/index.php?first=1&second=2 so you could just use `.` like `$link . '?parameter=X'`